# How to achieve real browser testing (launch browser) using Jenkins with Katalon studio?

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, launch, katalon-studio

I have configured Jenkins with Katalon studio but not able to launch the browser. Can anybody let me know what configuration we need to set it to launch (Chrome) browser in using Jenkins with Katalon studio.

I have set up below command and able to run my Job with Headless execution but I also need to the browser to get launch.

```
katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\NeerajS\Katalon\Automation\Automation.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/TC_01" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser will be not launched when you execute test from Jenkins. It is not a headless execution, but you can't see browser window during execution process, that is normal behaviour.

Comment: can we take a screenshot then?

Comment: @lahimadhe : No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instruction of this video: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/videos/jenkins_master_slave_configuration.html

My system looks like:

Jenkin is running on an Linux machine
Katalon Studio on Windows machine.

When I execute the tests with Jenkins, FF or IE browser are opened on the windows machine.